# How do Glide managed dependencies work with a build?

Tags: go, dependency-management, vendor

I am using Go 1.7 and trying out Glide.  The part I'm not getting is, Glide creates a vendor directory at $GOPATH/vendor.  But when go builds it is looking for a vendor directory at $GOPATH/src/github.com/vendor/.../...

So I'm missing the part that happens between installing/updating dependencies and making them available to my program during a build.

Comment: `Glide creates a vendor directory at $GOPATH/vendor`, that should not be. glide creates a vendor directory within your project folder (not to confuse with GOPATH). the project folder is more like the cwd where you created the `main.go` file. glide pulls dependencies into this vendor project, this has tbd before any attempt to build. I can t find the ref anymore, keep in mind that when go resolves a package path, it takes the longest one (vendor path within your project is, thus, always the longest).

Answer (score 0):

Adding the answer for the next poor soul that comes along.

If you're coming from the Java world, and you are used to the src directory being at the root of your project... Go says you are wrong.  As the commenter indicated, your project path is $GOPATH/src/[github.com]/username/projectname and that is where you should do your "glide init".

That will create the glide.yaml file in the correct spot so "glide install" will create the vendor directory at $GOPATH/src/githost/username/projectname/vendor and then your go builds will work as expected.

Hopefully this will clear it up for other folks who might have similar questions.